# General polynomial equation I've made

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For quite a while, from time to time I worked on a way to create a general nth degree/polynomial equation and I think it'd be great to show it to others as I think it doesn't have any mistakes and it is as simple as it can get.

So here is the general equation that I ask you to review:

$v_{0}+\sum_{i=1}^d v_{i}x^{i}=0$

*Where $d$ is the degree of the equation and $v$ is a coefficient.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, that's indeed what a general polynomial equation looks like. A couple remarks:

You can rewrite the term as $\sum_{i=0}^d v_i x^i$, since $x^0 = 1$ and therefore simplify it a little further. Also, $v$ is not really *a* variable, there are actually $d+1$ many of them, namely $v_0, \dots, v_d$.

Also note that $d$ could actually be larger than the degree of the equation, choose for example $d = 2$, $v_0 = 1, v_1 = 1, v_2 = 0$. This choice results in the equation $1 + x + 0x^2 = 0$, which has degree 1.

Comment: Oh, yes you're correct about $v$ not being a variable (it's a coefficient) and I guess I could've simplified the equation even further.

Comment: But I did have a version of my formula that was similar to that and one thing I found out is that in a such form of the general equation $x=0$ no matter what, because 0 + 0 + ... + 0 = 0, but that can't happen, (we know that not all equations have a solution of $x=0$) because in the summation you provided it starts with $v_{0}x^{0}$ and if $x=0$ then it's undefined, unless we say that $0^{0} = 1$. So to fix that I took $v_{0}$ out of the summation.

Comment: When working with polynomials, it is common to define $0^0$ as $1$. Essentially for this exact reason.